# Library not loaded: @rpath/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit

Tags: ios, facebook, carthage

I just start using Carthage and added `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit` to my project. I added them under my target's `General>Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`.

When running the app I'm getting: `Library not loaded: @rpath/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit`.

Is there any additional setup required to make this work? Maybe I'm missing something?
Thanks for any suggestions!

```
dyld[83163]: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit
  Referenced from: /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
  Reason: tried: '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bofellgqfanzxiczrleafuilfnvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file)Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics
  Referenced from: /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
  Reason: tried: '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuotoneAcademy-bofellgqfanzxiczrleafuilfnvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' (no such file)
Library not loaded: @rpath/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit
  Referenced from: /Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
  Reason: tried: '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bofellgqfanzxiczrleafuilfnvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5844632B-ED51-4F86-9587-18047A570EB1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/18218705-7148-4778-9A82-79D36BB48A13/Academy.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' (no such file), '/Users/Admin/Li
```

Comment: I am confused with the same problem now. Have you solved it?

Comment: @Zou i am confused with the same problem too, have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I was able to solve it by updating all the facebook pods.

In order to do this, first of all you need to [update your Cocoapod "repo"](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_repo_update).
"repo" is a file in your system that has the latest versions for all the pods. You can achieve this by typing this command in your terminal:

```
 pod repo update
```

For a clean approach you need to remove all the current installed pods from your XCode project by this command:

```
pod deintegrate
```

You can also achieve this by removing the "Pods" directory and "Podfile.lock" from your project, but I suggest using the command.

After this, you need to edit your `Podfile` and remove all the versions from FB pods to ensure that the latest pod will download and implement in your project. For example, change this:

```
 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 16.0'
 pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics', '~> 16.0'
```

to this:

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics'
```

SIDE NOTE: remember some newer vesions of pods (including Facebook pods require higher iOS versions. you can check this out by going to this website: [Cocoapods.org](https://cocoapods.org/) and search for your desired pod (for our problem FBAEMKit) and look for specs.

(Facebook pods version '16' and above require minimum iOS of '12')

Then you need to install pods:

```
pod install
```

After this if you wanna double check you can check the outdated pods with this command:

```
pod outdated
```

You wouldn't need to do this if you've already completed the steps above thoroughly.

Thats it! Hope it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using CocoaPods and have a similar issue. In my case, I solved it by change the Podfile linkage from (static linking) :

```
`use_frameworks! :linkage => static`
```

to something like this (dynamic linking) :

```
`use_frameworks!`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CocoaPods and have a similar issue.
In my case, I solved it by replacing it with FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework downloaded from GitHub.
I'm curious that the FBSDKCoreKit_Basics file downloaded from GitHub is larger than the file I got with pod install.